# from where data inserted in TreeNode table in tfs project datawarehouse?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have created one Project In TFS and generating custom report for daily billable hours and that generated database related that project and used datawarehouse db.
problem is that there is one table I have used called **TreeNode** that need to used it but I don't know used of treenode table.

example I have created Student project in tfs and automatically generate tfs_Student db in sql server and in this db generate many views and tables there is one table **treenode**  from where entry added in this table.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Have you been editing one of the TFS collection databases?

Comment: I need to generate custom report of billable hours where I entered in tfs so in tfs collection db contain one table treenode why this table used? any other way to get all working hour from tfs

Comment: Can you provide the sample for report of billable? For TFS 2013,the TreeNode table stores the information of Iterations and Areas.

Answer (score 0):

Since TFS/VSTS is an effort tracking system and not a time tracking system it is a loosing battle to try and track billable time as part of TFS/VSTS. I have worked with many companies that have tried to do what you want and almost all have failed. For those that succeeded the effort spent is dis-proporional to the value gained.

I would suggest that you should track Time to Project and Capex vs Opex separately in a dedicated system. Since "software task" and "project task" is not really the same thing there is little to no duplication between the systems...

I use Freshbooks for billing to customers and VSTS for building software. There are however many other tools out there.

Comment: yes you get my point try and track billable time as part of TFS/VSTS but sometime all failed.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are just looking to apply a time-tracking utility on TFS, check this question [TFS - Time tracking and Bug tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487254/tfs-time-tracking-and-bug-tracking)  - there are apparently various options.

A suggested way is **adding some time fields to your task work items** just like *Vaccano's* answer.

Another way is connecting  your **Excel** application to the TFS2013 analysis cube and you will be able to get the hours administered to a task and even the date and time that these hours have been administered.

Comment: Patrick, you can't get the hours associated to a task from the cube, only a guess at the hours completed based on a developer entered value. Not very accurate. Not accurate enough for billing... Nor for capex vs open.